# How to send a Rectangle to a function which takes a rectangle argument, in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider I have a rectangle like this:

```
Point p1(100,100);
Point p2(300,200);
Graph_lib::Rectangle r(p1,p2);
```

And also I have a function that takes a rectangle and returns a Point of that, say, top-left corner of that rectangle. For example:

```
Point N(Graph_lib::Rectangle R1);
```

My question is that, first, how to send that `Rectangle r(p1,p2)` to the `Point N(Graph_lib::Rectangle R1)` function? And then, how to return a Point from that function?

My IDE is visual studio 2012.
This is the code I ran and got the error:
*Error  8   error C2248: 'Graph_lib::Shape::Shape' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Graph_lib::Shape'  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\graph.h    212*

```
#include <Simple_window.h>

Point  N(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);
Point  s(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);
Point  e(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);
Point  w(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);
Point ne(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);
Point se(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);
Point nw(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);
Point sw(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);
Point center(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);

//*******************************************************

int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib; 

    Simple_window win(Point(100,100), 600,400, "Connection_Points");    
    Point p1(200,100);
    Point p2(400,200);
    Graph_lib::Rectangle r (p1,p2);
    Mark m(N(r),'x');
    win.attach(m);
    win.wait_for_button();
}

//*******************************************************************

Point N(Graph_lib::Rectangle r)
{
    return r.point(0);
}

//*************************************************

Point  s(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);

//*************************************************

Point  e(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);

//*************************************************

Point  w(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);

//*************************************************

Point ne(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);

//*************************************************

Point se(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);

//*************************************************

Point nw(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);

//*************************************************

Point sw(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);

//*************************************************

Point center(Graph_lib::Rectangle r);
```

Comment: Please read any introductory book or tutorial in C++, this will be covered there.

Comment: @Mat Oddly enough, when I suggested the same to a question exhibiting the same level of knowledge/research I got scolded by half the stackoverflow community for being rude. Reputation deficiency?

Comment: @o_weisman maybe the grumpiest SO users are asleep right now?

Comment: @Mat: No, I have the PPP book and it's an exercise from it. There hasn't been anything about this issue till now. That's unfortunate that someone gives this question a negative vote. I'm so sorry I use stackoverflow.com for help.

Comment: @abbasi: Stack Overflow's for specific programming issues, it's no substitute for a books, training, etc. What you're asking is covered in basic learning material for C++ (same for all other languages). Please take some time to read at least one book or comprehensive tutorial.

Comment: If you book really gives you exercises without explaining anything before, throw it away... That´s exactly what it should *not* do. And `Point p3 = N(r);` ?

Comment: @Mat: You think I brought this problem from my own brain? No, as I said, it's in the PPP book (http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/). I've read the book, and this is in chapter 13 of that. When I have said I want to learn Programming from forums? It's really a misunderstanding.

Comment: @abbasi: calling functions is covered in chapters 4, 5 and 8 (at least) in that book.

Comment: @Mat: It sounds that you haven't read problem properly but anyway, OK. You are expert and I'm novice, and apparently you are aware of that book. I bet you can't to solve a simple exercise using all the contexts which are covered even until chapter 13 (no only chapter 8, ..) of that book. If your are right answer this problem using those contexts. If you answer this, I swear I never ask any question on Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: If this is a negative question so how all of you so-called experts are unable to solve it using those 13 chapters of that fu... book?

Comment: @Mat, Why you don't try to assay your skills and have a code for that simple exercise!?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to specify the argument instead of the function parameter when you call the function

For example

```
Point p1(100,100);
Point p2(300,200);
Graph_lib::Rectangle r(p1,p2);

Point p3 =  N( r );
```

**EDIT:** It seems you are speaking about the book by B. Straustrup.

In this case the function can be defined the following way

```
Point N( const Graph_lib::Rectangle &R1 )
{
   return R1.point( 0 );
}
```

Only I do not know whether struct Point is defined in namespace Graph_lib. If so then the function will be defined as

```
Graph_lib::Point N( const Graph_lib::Rectangle &R1 )
{
   return R1.point( 0 );
}
```

Or

```
Graph_lib::Point TopLeftPoint( const Graph_lib::Rectangle &r )
{
   return r.point( 0 );
}
```

Comment: It's very simple Vlad. I had two questions, the second was how to return a point from that function. you've left it in answer.

Comment: @abbasi Your second question is incorrect. It should sound as how to define the function. I do not know how the rectangle is defined so I can say nothing. Show the definition of the rectangle.

Comment: So your answer is meaningless. This is the exact context of the exercise from page 477 of PPP: _Define functions n(), s(), e(), w(), center(), ne(), se(), sw() and nw(). Each takes a Rectangle argument and returns a Point. These functions define connection points on and in the rectangle. For example, nw(r) is the northwest (top-left corner) of a rectangle called r_.

Comment: @abbasi I DO not know what book you are speaking about. But in any case if you want to get as you get a complete answer you have to ask a complete question.

Comment: @Vlad: I wrote that code also but got errors. The main one is, _Error 8 error C2248: 'Graph_lib::Shape::Shape' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Graph_lib::Shape' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\graph.h 212_.

Comment: @abbasi AFAIK member function point of class Shape is public.

Comment: PS: FLTK version 1.3.2 is completely and properly installed on the IDE. And also there isn't even a bit info about the two questions I mentioned at the context of the question. Now is it my fault that I have problem with that exercise?

Comment: @abbasi I showed you how to define and call the function.

Comment: Hhhhhhh. Hey, everyone how has even a month period of learning the C++ programming knows how to define and call the functions. I asked a specific question which is special for advanced forums. But all of you couldn't answer this simple question and though I posted the error but again no one of you could determine where the problem is. With respect to you, but you aren't expert at all. You gave my question negative vote because it was such difficult that all of you were cripple of solving it. I don't care about that -5 vote because I know what novice persons gave it me.

Comment: @abbasi I showed you how the function can be defined as called. As for your error then I do not know what code are you running.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Look at the code in the body of the question please.

Comment: @abbasi And what is the statement where the error occured?

Comment: I would used F10 and F11 to debugging the code in visual studio 2012 when I would code in previous chapters (console applications). But now for these applications and for this code when I press f10 that error appears. And program doesn't go to the debugging environment apparently.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: If you would like to see the reason of the problem, have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/132086/

Comment: @abbasi I already SHOWED you how the function shall be defined. What iis the problem?! Are you unable simply copy and paste?!

Comment: At the time I noted the '&' in your code and also wrote the code just like what you have wrote. But got error. I don't know what was the mistake of that time. Anyway, it's clear that you solved some part of the problem.

Comment: @savemap If you copied the definition exactly as I wrote then I think there should not be an error.

Comment: Look Vlad, there is some important thing rather than what you try to prove. At that address when I wrote the error message "he" concluded that the problem is about preventing from copying. So using the _&_ then, was completely logical.

Comment: @abbasi AFAIK the copy constructor of class Shape is defined as private. So in class Rectangle the copy constructor is defined implicitly as deleted. So you may pass objects of type Rectangle by reference.

Comment: Yes. But if you would like to participate in this exercise more, please say your talk about this. When you used the _r.point(0)_ it indicated to the top-left corner of the rectangle _r_. But what about other corners? How to use the height or width of _r_ to indicate other points in those functions?

Comment: @abbasi The rectangle stores only one top-left point and also width and height. So you can get the bottom-right point using the top-left point along with the width and height. I think you should close this question.

Comment: I would know that the way is that. But by what statements? I used some ones like, r.h or r.height but got error.

Comment: The problem is solved. Again at that address. The question is now closed. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply rectangle is:

```
Rect(int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

Your function is defined as:

```
Point N(Rectangle rect)
{
  Point anypt = new Point(10,30);
  return anypt;
}

Point p1(100,100);
Point p2(300,200);
Graph_lib::Rectangle r(p1,p2);
```

You can call function `N` and pass parameter rectangle `r` as:

Point p = N(r);

Comment: You just wrote C#, bro.

Comment: Or Java, but doesn't look like C++.

Comment: It doesn't work, bro. I give some explanation about Rectangle in next comment.

Comment: it is written in  c++

Comment: In the PPP book, there are just (until this chapter) two ways of defining a rectangle. Either, _Rectangle(Point xy, int h, int w)_ or _ Rectangle(Point x, Point y)_. And also that _Point(10,30);_ really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that, first, how to send that Rectangle r(p1,p2) to the Point N(Graph_lib::Rectangle R1) function? And then, how to return a Point from that function?

**A1**

The right terminology is "pass", not "send". - You need to *pass* an object of type `Graph_lib::Rectangle` to a function called N, which returns a Point object. Think of this in terms of what you know from mathematics. Think of, say, simple function `f(x) = 2*x`. If you *pass* a number 2 as argument to the function `f`, it will return an integer number 4.

Now let's go back to the problem. Here is the simple C++ code as an answer to your first question:

```
// Note: this is your own code
Point p1(100, 100);
Point p2(300, 200);
Graph_lib::Rectangle rec(p1, p2);
// Now let's call the function N and get the Point from it
Point resultPoint = N(rec); // Here we PASS the rec object to the function N()
```

voila! Now you have `resultPoint` variable of the Point type that you can play with.

**A2**

Question two has been answered in the same C++ line where we call the N() function. :)

Comment: First, you haven't read the comments being exchanged among and the answer, Vlad gave, to/with me. Second, you haven't read the question with its complete deep meaning. Third, answer does mean answer not semi-answer. Thanks for teaching me the terminology.

Comment: Are you real? I quoted your questions! You can read them yourself. Now I wonder why I wasted time answering question of a person with such attitude!

Comment: About the time you spent for answering my questions, you are right. It's a kindness. But I'd know what I'm saying and they are all, right. And I also wonder why when someone indicates the mistakes of someone else, that person should give him, at return, the negative vote! No problem man. I have -6 at this, if I had -60 I wouldn't care still. As I said, the question is closed now.